# HTTP response body is obfuscated

Tags: python, http

I'm using `httplib.HTTPConnection` to submit an HTTP POST request. I get a 200 response status but the response data looks obfuscated or something. 
When I submit the request in Firefox, the response is displayed fine.

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.foo.com")
conn.request('POST', '/foo', postdata, headers)
resp = conn.getresponse()
conn.close()
print resp.read()
```

Comment: Did you look at the headers? Perhaps you were served a *compressed* response? Is there a `Content-Encoding` header?

Comment: In any case, we cannot see the response you got, so we cannot otherwise help you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes. It was gzip'ed. Thank you

Comment: @scrappedcola I was under the impression python's HTTPSConnection didn't do anything

Comment: I flagged to have this question deleted and a moderator declined it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the response is unexpectedly 'binary', look at the Content-Encoding header. Most likely you are being served a compressed response; it can be either `gzip` or `deflate`.

If you the encoding is `gzip`, decode it with:

```
import zlib

decompressor = zlib.decompressobj(16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
data = decompressor.decompress(response_body)
```

For `deflate`, you'd have to try both a default compressor and one with `-zlib.MAX_WBITS`:

```
try:
    decompressor = zlib.decompressobj()
    data = decompressor.decompress(response_body)
except zlib.error:
    decompressor = zlib.decompressobj(-zlib.MAX_WBITS)
    data = decompressor.decompress(response_body)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer, you could probably disable encoding by setting the [`Accept-Encoding`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression#Content-Encoding_tokens) header to `identity`.

```
headers = {
    # ...
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity",
    # ...
}
```